# Can not find swagger-ui page

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I've got a problem with swagger ui. I am using these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

So, as you can see, for swagger I am using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

These are my swagger settings in application.properties

```
# Swagger settings
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
```

Here is my SecurityFilterChain. I thought that Spring Security might be blocking my requests, but it looks like it is not

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                    .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/users/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            );

    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}
```

I am trying to find swagger ui at this url

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

and I am getting **Whitelabel Error Page**. Api-docs page

```
http://localhost:8080/api-docs
```

works perfectly, so where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in wrong dependency. I was using this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

But looks like this dependency used only for /api-docs path, without ui, so I checked my older project and copied dependency from there

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

And now everything works fine. Always need to check if you are using correct dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you access to`/swagger-ui.html` you will have an redirect to `/swagger-ui/index.html`, just change the path to:

```
.requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
```

And try to open swagger url:

`http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`

**UPDATE**

Declare a custom configuration for OpenApi

```
@Configuration
public class ApiConfig {

  @Bean
  public OpenAPI customOpenApi() {
    return new OpenAPI().info(new Info().title("Application API")
            .version("version")
            .description("description")
            .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0")
                .url("http://springdoc.org"))
            .contact(new Contact().name("username")
                .email("test@gmail.com")));
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope, still not working... Maybe something with my Spring Boot version? I am using Spring Boot 3.0.2

Comment: Did you declare an `OpenAPI` Bean ?

Comment: i am sure you didnt declare this Bean, i`m going to update my answer with an example

Comment: No, i did not, but i changed version of dependency from 2.2.0 to 2.0.4 and it is working now, i dont know why

Comment: i updated my answer, with an example

Comment: Okay, the problem was not in OpenApi bean, but in wrong dependency... I just took a dependency for swagger ui from my older project and everything is working now, still thank you for showing an example of OpenApi bean configuration